# How do I know what MOSFET to use?

Tags: arduino, mosfet, switches

I am using an Arduino Nano that has output pins of 5 volts. I want to use the Arduino nano S pin to open and close a MOSFET for powering on and off a Benewake TFmini Plus distance sensor ( http://en.benewake.com/product/detail/5c345cd0e5b3a844c472329b.html ). The TFmini Plus sensor has a power consumption of 85mW~550mW and runs on 5V. What MOSFET should I use as a switch to connect the 5 volts on and off for powering the TFmini Plus and have the switch controlled by the signal pin from the Arduino Nano?

I am new to this and any information on understanding how to learn what MOSFET to use is extremely helpful. MOSFETs are new to me. Thank you for any advice you can offer.

Comment: For a high side switch from 5V you search for a Pch Enh FET with “logic level drive “ features ie. where RdsOn is rated at -4.5V or less and chose RdsOn to be <100mW at rated current or <5% of load Req whichever is lower in a package of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an OnSemi [NDP6020P](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NDP6020P-D.PDF), which is a P-channel MOSFET (for high side switching) and is through-hole and logic level. There are very few through-hole logic-level MOSFETs. Many, many more possibilities in SMT.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBKCBH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The datasheet for that (your) product is behind a registration wall so it's not going to get evaluated by many here, including me. If you have GPIO outputs connected to the device, be sure to drive them low or float them before  turning off the device. Also note that LOW = ON.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is it possible to have low equal off and when I use the S pin from the Arduino to give high to the mosfet to switch the TFmini Plus sensor on? Why does low have to equal on? Can a mosfet be used so that low or no power to it from the Arduino means the 5 volts is switched off and does not go through to the sensor? Your insight is highly welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: The 5 volts to power the sensor is from a 5 volt pin that is on when the Arduino is on, but I don’t want it to go through to power the sensor unless the Arduino sends high to a mosfet. Is it possible to use the mosfet as a switch that when it receives low or no power from the Arduino S pin the mosfet will not pass the 5 volts on and When the mosfet receives high it will open to pass the 5 volts onto the sensor? Sorry for my lack of understanding. This is very new to me. I’m eager to learn.

Comment: Yes , you could add another transistor to invert the output, such as a 2N7000. Decrease the 100K to 4.7K.